# Variables and Assign range to it in Python

Tags: python

I want to assign a variable called `R` and it should contain integers 1 to 3000; how do I write that code in python. I am new one. So can you help me to write that?

Comment: That cording might be this: `R = range(1, 3001)`.

Comment: Hey still I can't ask questions due to this question I want to lift that band. This was my first question.

Comment: You could make a new account, and use it to ask less vague and trivial questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `range` to create a mutable list, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

```
R = range(1,3001)
```

Note the slice idea when using range, you produce the integers between the range (**inclusive** of the start and **exclusive** of the end):

```
>>> range(1,2)
[1]
>>> range(0,1)
[0]
>>> range(1)
[0]
>>> range(1,10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1,11)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> range(0,10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And you can also use the step feature, e.g.

```
>>> even = range(1,10,2)
>>> even
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> odd = range(1,10,2)
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> tens = range(0,101,10)
>>> tens
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to create a list of integers from 1 - 3000. The easiest way to do that in Python is to use the `range` function.

```
R = range(1, 3001)
```

You could then iterate over the list like so:

```
for i in R:
    print i
```

Would output

```
1
2
3
4
...etc
```

Comment: I have data as follows  I want to define R in this file how can I do it. Later I am going to call this data one by one i another file.                                                             R[1]=['1SOL','OW',1,1.504,2.758,0.682],
R[2]=['1SOL','HW1',2,1.4788,2.7853,0.7702]
R[3]=['1SOL','HW2',3,1.464,2.823,0.6243]
R[4]=['2SOL','OW',4,1.521,0.951,2.205]
R[5]=['2SOL','HW1',5,1.596,0.978,2.152]
R[6]=['2SOL','HW2',6,1.446,0.994,2.164]
R[7]=['3SOL','OW',7,2.152,2.902,2.548]
R[8]=['3SOL','HW1',8,2.1351,2.96546,2.6185]
R[9]=['3SOL','HW2',9,2.2397,2.9242,2.5168]

Comment: It's not at all clear what that means. If you want to ask a good question, try showing the input you have and the output you are trying to get.